# VLOOKUP within a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to convert a month name to a yyyy-mm format within a query.

I'm not sure how to do it with a single formula, but I did a table with all the months, because the source data is in yyyy-mm and the dashboard I'm building has the name of the month in plain English.

[image]

So I do a VLOOKUP, the user selects the name of the month in a dropdown list and I want to display the data related to that month as per the query.

```
=QUERY(data!$A$1:$R,"SELECT COUNT(H) WHERE C = '"&VLOOKUP($G$3,backend!$A$2:$B$13,2,0)&"'")
```

It returns nothing
[image]

but if I highlight the formula, I get the expected value, but it's not rendering as I expect
[image]

Comment: What data type you are using to `Column C`? Are they true date or `YYYY-MM`  as string. Can you share a sample workbook? I think you no need vlookup. You can achieve it with single query formula.

Comment: Can you share with us a copy of your spreadsheet so that we may replicate your issue? It would seem that your formula involves at least two sheets ("data" and "backend").

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: sample database https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LMlsX0WoTnxCshuw9dprPse-DJx45Of851h1NKFCi8c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data in `C` column are text then you can use below formula (without additional lookup table if it is for current year).

```
=QUERY(A1:H6,"select count(H) where C='" & 
TEXT(DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(G3,3)&"-"&YEAR(TODAY())),"YYYY-MM") & "'")
```

If your date in `C` column are true date then you can try below formula-

```
=QUERY(A1:H6,"select count(H) where C>= date '" & 
TEXT(DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(G3,3)&"-"&YEAR(TODAY())),"YYYY-MM-dd") & "' and C <= date '" & 
TEXT(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(G3,3)&"-"&YEAR(TODAY())),0),"YYYY-MM-DD") & "'")
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try it next week, I'll get back to you after I test it out